# what is the right way to query different filters on dynamodb?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I save my `order` data on dyanmodb table. And the partition key is `orderId`, sort key is `timestamp`. Each order has many other attributes like `category,` userName`,` price`,` items`,` status`. I am going to build a filter service to let clients query order based on these attributes. Also I'd like to add a limit on the query for pagination. But I find some limitations on dynamodb.

In order to support querying different fields, I have two options:

- Create GSI for each attribute. It is very expensive but it supports query each attribute very performance. This solution doesn't support combine multiple attributes in the filter.
- Attach a filter expression on the `SCAN` to include attribute condition. `SCAN` is not very performance in the first place. Also the filter expression is applied after `limits`. Which means it is very likely to response less than users request limits.

so what is the good way to achieve this in dynamodb?

Comment: I don't think DynamoDB is a good use case for this. If you are on AWS, you could use an Elastic Search to perform the search and filtering part, and store the orders on DynamoDB. Using DynamoDB Streams, once you create an order, you index it on Elastic Search.

Comment: Another approach is to send documents to Elasticsearch and do all sorts of queries there.

Comment: I think your approach basically means to drop dynamodb and save all orders in Elastcisearch. What is the point to use dynamodb here?

Answer (score 0):

There is unfortunately no magic way to solve your problems. There is no DynamoDB feature which you missed. Indeed, as you said, making each of the attributes available for efficient queries requires a GSI which will cost you additional money - but that's reasonable. Indeed, as you said, there is no efficient way to search for an **intersection** of requirements on two different attribute. And indeed, the "limit" feature doesn't quite do what you want and you'll need to emulate your page size need in the client code (asking for more pages until your desired amount is recieved), potentially with unacceptably high latency.

It sounds that what you really need is a **search engine**. These have exactly the features that you asked for. You'll still be paying for these features (indexing of individual columns still takes up CPU and disk space, intersection of multiple attribute searches still requires significant work at query time) but search engines are designed for exactly these operations, and do them more efficiently and with lower latency (which is important for interactive searches, which are the bread-and-butter of search engines).

Answer (score 0):

You can add the limit for pagination using the limit attribute in the query. But can you please be more specific about your access patterns, is your clients going to query all the orders or only the orders belonging to them ?

Comment: Like what I said in the question, filters are applied after limits. Clients will query based on these values: category, userName, price, items, status. For admin clients, they can query orders from other clients.